# GLSL array of struct members locations

Tags: opengl, glsl

For example, I have code like this:

```
uniform struct MyStruct {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 projection;
    float f1;
    vec4 v1;
}, myStructs[4];
```

Can I be sure that location of `myStructs[1].projection` is location of `myStructs[0].projection` + 5?

I didn't find the exact information about this on khronos.org, but I found some blurry [statement](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location):

> ```
> struct Thingy
> {
>   vec4 an_array[3];
>   int foo;
> };
> layout(location = 2) uniform Thingy some_thingies[6];
> ```
>
> Each Thingy takes up 4 uniform locations; the first three going to
>   an_array and the fourth going to foo. Thus, some_thingies takes up 24
>   uniform locations.

It isn't clear here whether locations one after another. Perhaps about this somewhere is said more accurately?

Comment: "*It isn't clear here whether locations one after another.*" That's because it said how it works two sentences before that. However, that's irrelevant, because that entire section is about how uniform locations work when you *explicitly specify* those locations with a `layout(location=#)` qualifier. Without that qualifier, then the definitions in [this section](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management) take over.

Comment: @NicolBolas "_However, for structs (or arrays of structs), if the locations were not explicitly specified then the location of any particular element will have no relation to any other element. So you cannot count on the next element being one location index higher than the previous. This is true even for arrays of structs_", - does it mean that the statement "location of myStructs[1].projection is location of myStructs[0].projection + 5" is not true?

Comment: @NicolBolas or, can it be argued that location of myStructs[1].projection is location of myStructs[0].projection + countOfUsedUniforms(myStructs[0])?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need me to tell you what you just quoted. That paragraph specifies the cases to which the rules it outlines apply. You know whether your code fits that case. And the rule itself is very clear. So... what do you need me to say that isn't in what you quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example `uniform struct MyStruct` is a raw uniform whose member locations are [arbitrary and must be queried](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management):

> Uniform locations are unique to a specific program. If you do not explicitly assign a uniform to a location (via the OpenGL 4.3 or ARB_explicit_uniform_location feature mentioned above), then OpenGL will assign them **arbitrarily**.

Your second example `layout(location = 2) uniform Thingy some_thingies[6];` is defining a uniform block to which the following memory layout applies:

Quote [Memory layout](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Memory_layout):

> The specific size of basic types used by members of buffer-backed blocks is defined by OpenGL. However, implementations are allowed some latitude when assigning padding between members, as well as reasonable freedom to optimize away unused members. How much freedom implementations are allowed for specific blocks can be changed.
>
> There are four memory layout qualifiers: shared, packed, std140, and std430. Defaults can be set the same as for matrix ordering (eg: layout(packed) buffer; sets all shader storage buffer blocks to use packed). The default is shared.

So it seems that they are sequential in memory, but as *t.niese* points out: only `std140` and `std430` provide you with those guarantees (note that `std430` *can only be used with shader storage blocks, not uniform blocks*). Since the default layout is `shared` some parts of your uniform might have been optimised out or padded differently, depending on your driver.

Use [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetUniformLocation#Description) to query each location of the members separately:

> Uniform variables that are structures or arrays of structures may be queried by calling glGetUniformLocation for each field within the structure. The array element operator "[]" and the structure field operator "." may be used in name​ in order to select elements within an array or fields within a structure. The result of using these operators is not allowed to be another structure, an array of structures, or a subcomponent of a vector or a matrix. Except if the last part of name​ indicates a uniform variable array, the location of the first element of an array can be retrieved by using the name of the array, or by using the name appended by "[0]".

Comment: `std140` and `std430` give a defined memory layout, so you don't need to query each location (you should only avoid `vec3` in the `std140` as some implementation mess the layout up for that). Only for `shared` and `packed` the compiler has complete freedom about the layout, so the layout is implementation-dependent and needs to be queried.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the comment, I tried to incorporate that into the answer.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: This question is not about uniform *blocks*; it's about a raw uniform variable which happens to be a struct. So the first half of this post is irrelevant.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: "*is defining a uniform block*" This is still wrong. It's still a "raw uniform"; it simply has an location explicitly specified, and the array/struct elements of it will have their locations sequentially allocated based on the explicit specification. There is no uniform block here, and even if it was, uniform blocks *don't have locations* at all.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly specify the location of the uniform variable, the locations of arrays of non-basic types [are not strictly defined](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management), relative to the location of any particular member of that array. So you *must* query the location of every member of every array/struct that you use.

Or just [explicitly specify the location](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location) with `layout(location)`. That's a much easier option; those are explicitly required to allocate their locations sequentially. And for bonus points, you don't have to query anything.